# Cannot get twitter Oauth authentication to work with nuxt-auth

Tags: vue.js, oauth, vuex, nuxt-auth

I am trying to authenticate a web app with twitter but I can't seem to find it In the docs and it's not included in the demos provided. My question is, is there no direct support from nuxt auth again or I can just follow the same configuration as that of facebook and / google.

NB: I followed the same configuration but I kept getting error. However, if it requires a tweak to make it work, please don't hesitate to share. Thanks!

Comment: Providing the error would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Actually there's no error. Twitter Oauth implementation is not included in the nuxt auth docs. So I want to know if there's a way I can get it to work with nuxt auth